# Getting Special Item Labels to be Cited Correctly in the Index

Tags: tcolorbox, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1#2{%
\imki@wrindexentrysplit {#1}{#2}{\arabic{enumi}}\endgroup \imki@showidxentry
{#1}{#2}\@esphack}
\makeatother

\newtcbox{\purplebox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,
     notitle,
     colframe=purple!20!black,
     colback=purple!50!black,
     top=4pt,
     left=5pt,
     right=5pt,
     bottom=2pt,
     fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
     colupper=white,
     tcbox raise base,
     #1}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\olditem\item
\newcommand*{\purpleboxitems}{%
    \renewcommand*{\item}[1][]{%
        \ifblank{##1}{\olditem}{\olditem[\purplebox{##1}]}%
    }%
}
\setlist{
    label*={\purplebox{\arabic*}},
    before=\purpleboxitems,
    after=\let\item\olditem,
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}
\item Regular item.\index{First regular item}
\item Regular item.\index{Second regular item}
\item[2*] Special item.\index{Special item}
\item Regular item.\index{Second regular item}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

which produces on the first page

[image]

followed by the Index:

[image]

Notice that the index cites the correct item label as long as no modification has been made to the default label; however, when in the MWE, the item label (number) is changed to `2*`, although it is given correctly in the enumerated list, it is not cited correctly in the Index---being given as `2` instead of `2*`.

QUESTION: How may the above code be modified in order to have such "special items" be cited correctly in the Index?

Thank you.

Comment: it's not dropping the `*`  you are not writing the optional argument at all, try `\item[9*] Special item.\index{Special item}` you still get 2 written (the current value of the enumi counter from the previous item.

Comment: @David Carlisle Unless I am not seeing something, `\item[9*] Special item.\index{Special item}` differs from what I have because of `[9*]` in place of `[2*]`. When I run what you suggest, the Index still produces a "page citation" of 2 instead of the desired `9*`. Perhaps I am misinterpreting your comment.

Comment: yes exactly, I read the original question as saying the index processing was dropping the `*` from `2*` but I just mean that it's not doing that it is dropping the whole label and re-using the label from the previous item. so the fact that you got a 2 from `2*` is sort of coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeindex` sorts index entries by their keys and pages, hence it (seems that it) requires each page in one and only one "numeric" forms (digital, arabic, and roman).

Here in your example `2*` is not a valid "numeric" form, hence I'm afraid you have to do page encapsulation (`\index{<key>|<cmd>}), manually or automatically if you patch the` \index` internals.

A manually page encapsulation example:

```tex
% define
\newcommand{\idxStarred}[1]{#1*}
% then use
\item[2*] Special item.\index{Special item|idxStarred}
```

Note this doesn't solve all the problems. For example, it can't make all the non-starred index entries smaller than those starred when sorting.

---

Update: This new attempt will split the "special page" into page and page-aux parts (using `l3regex`), then auto insert page encapsulation. Therefore

```tex
% input
\item[2*] Special item\index{special item}

% i) will generate, in `.idx` file
\indexentry{Special item|myindexPrintPage{*}}{2}

% ii) will become, in `.ind` file, after running `makeindex`
\item Special item, \myindexPrintPage{*}{2}

% iii) will finally typeset as, in `.pdf` file
Special item, 2*
```

```tex
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_myindex_page_tl      % beginning digits
\tl_new:N \l_myindex_page_aux_tl  % anything left

\regex_const:Nn \c_begining_digits_regex { ^(\d+) }

\msg_new:nnn {myindex} {wrong-page-pattern}
  {Wrong page pattern ``\tl_to_str:n{#1}''}

% split special page into page_tl and page_aux_tl
% e.g. 
%   input: special page == "2*"
%   output: page_tl == "2", page_aux_tl == "*"
\cs_new:Nn \myindex_split_page:n
  {
    \regex_split:NnNTF \c_begining_digits_regex {#1} \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        % now the seq is "<empty>, page_tl, page_aux_tl"
        \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_myindex_page_aux_tl
        \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_myindex_page_tl
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn {myindex} {wrong-page-pattern} {#1} }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \myindex_split_page:n {V}

\makeatletter
\cs_set_eq:NN \myindexPrintPage \@swaptwoargs

\def\@wrindex#1#2{%
  \ifdefined\@currentitem
    \myindex_split_page:V \@currentitem
    \imki@wrindexentrysplit{#1}
      {#2|myindexPrintPage{\l_myindex_page_aux_tl}}
      {\l_myindex_page_tl}%
    \endgroup
    \imki@showidxentry{#1}{#2}%
  \else
    \imki@wrindexentrysplit{#1}{#2}{\arabic{enumi}}%
    \endgroup
    \imki@showidxentry{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\let\olditem\item
\newcommand*{\purpleboxitems}{%
  \renewcommand*{\item}[1][]{%
    \ifblank{##1}
      {\let\@currentitem\@undefined\olditem}
      {\def\@currentitem{##1}\olditem[\purplebox{##1}]}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newtcbox{\purplebox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,
   notitle,
   colframe=purple!20!black,
   colback=purple!50!black,
   top=4pt,
   left=5pt,
   right=5pt,
   bottom=2pt,
   fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
   colupper=white,
   tcbox raise base,
   #1}

\setlist{
  label*={\purplebox{\arabic*}},
  before=\purpleboxitems,
  after=\let\item\olditem,
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{enumerate}
  \item     Regular item.\index{First regular item}
  \item     Regular item.\index{Second regular item}
  \item[2*] Special item.\index{Special item}
  \item[2+] Another special item.\index{Special item}
  \item     Regular item.\index{Second regular item}
  \item[3$\neq$] Third special item.\index{Special item}
\end{enumerate}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer; but it seems that it works for  * only. If I, say, changed the * to a +, then it appears that I would introduce another `\newcommand`. This certainly  is helpful for specific cases as long as there aren't too many of them. If possible, I was looking for a way to print the `contents` of `\item[contents]` in the index, whatever such `contents` may be. Would you know of a way to accomplish this general case? Thanks again.

Comment: Seems [`xindy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xindy) provides a user-configurable page sorting interface. It's commands `define-location-class` and `define-location-class-order` may be helpful ([manual/command-list](http://www.xindy.org/doc/manual-3.html)). If you could describe how you would sort the page field with "whatever such contents may be", maybe I can try sth.

Comment: +1 Sorry I wasn't more clear earlier. Consider that contents would be a number followed  by one symbol such as an asterisk, or a plus sign, or an inequality sign, or the like. Unfortunately, `xindy` is not an option for me. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, I've added a new attempt to my answer. Welcome to try and test it.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to reproduce your output, with the exception that at the top, it prints a distorted version (with a dot at the bottom) of what comes after the ^ in the 13th line: `\regex_const:Nn \c_begining_digits_regex { ^(\d+) }`. Based on the error messages I get, I seems like some `$$` are missing; but when I try to insert them, I keep getting error messages. Bu thank you very much for your update.

Comment: Any test cases?

Comment: So far, I just ran the code you posted; and as I said, I get error messages starting at the aforesaid line 13. I haven't tried any other items. I had been trying to get the code to compile successfully on my end. I am assuming the code as posted runs successfully on your end. Again, it seems to want a pair of `$$` somewhere.

Comment: It seems you're working in texlive 2016 or before. At that time `l3regex` module was not even exist., hence you will receive errors `Undefined control sequence. l.14 \regex_const:Nn` and `Missing $ inserted. l.14 \regex_const:Nn \c_begining_digits_regex { ^`. (Please post the exact error messages next time.) I'll see if the dependence on `l3regex` can be removed.

Comment: Yes, the system I use is prior to 2017. Perhaps that's the problem. I would gladly post the some of the errors I get, but I've never been able to post a picture in the comments; and posting it as part of the question would raise confusion I fear. But thank you kindly for all your efforts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131571/discussion-between-muzimuzhi-z-and-mlchristians).

Comment: Thank you, but for time constraints, I must pass. I thank you again for your efforts on my behalf. I ought to be able to make good use of your first answer, as I doubt I will have very many "special cases" in the future to consider, which can be handled nicely by (one or more) `newcommands` that you proposed in your first posting.